# Dynamic (i.e. Runtime Configurable) Log Configuration for Django + Celery based application

Tags: python, django, logging, dynamic, celery

We have a need to customize the log levels on the server at runtime.  We are building a SAAS application using Django, and we have to be able to enable logging per tenant eventually.  I am trying to find the best way of doing it.

As a first step, I created a way to dynamically change log levels (for the whole application).  I see there are no examples of doing it.  I am note sure if one one tried something like this so far, and what are the pitfalls I should be watching out for.

Here is my code so far.  Appreciate if anyone can shed light on specific pitfalls I am going to run into.  Also appreciate any input on how to control logging per tenant and module, short of creating logger per tenant per module:

```
import threading
import logging.config
import time
import os
import traceback

class LogConfigWatcher(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, storage, location):
        self.last_known_time = None
        self.storage = storage
        self.location = location
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            mod_time = os.path.getmtime(self.location)
            if(mod_time != self.last_known_time):
                try:
                    with file(self.location) as f:
                        print("Configuring logging . . .")
                        config = eval(f.read())
                        logging.config.dictConfig(config['handler_config'])
                        logging.config.dictConfig(config['logger_config'])
                    self.last_known_time = mod_time
                except:
                    traceback.print_exc()
                    print "Failed to Configure the log"
                    pass
            time.sleep(5)

class LogConfigHolder(object):
    def __init__(self, storage, location):
        self.storage = storage
        self.location = location

        self.initialize(storage, location)

    def initialize(self, storage, location):
        self.pid = os.getpid()
        print "Starting thread for %s" % self.pid
        self.thread = LogConfigWatcher(storage, location)
        self.thread.setDaemon(True)
        self.thread.start()

    def is_alive(self):
        if os.getpid() != self.pid:
            return False
        return self.thread.isAlive()

    def restart(self):
        if not self.is_alive():
            self.initialize(self.storage, self.location)
```

Comment: Try this: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes and this: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#network-logging

Comment: My question is more to do with how can I change log levels while the process is still running.  I read them before asking the question and not able to find anything there.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure your given code comes close to what is already conjured up by the writers of the Logging module itself.

You use a separate thread in your program that listens for configuration requests every time a logging event occurs. The logging server, in turn, holds the configuration file(s) which you can adapt. Changes will be picked up on the next logging event.

The original author of the Logger module might provide you with more insight [here](http://www.red-dove.com/python_logging.html#onthefly), do note that this manual is a bit outdated. The official Python docs for Logging has an example of configuring such a Logging server/client setup: [Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#configuration-server-example).

And, as is always the case when complexity rises, such a setup does have a slight performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an application to solve this problem. the configuration is in the database, and many configurations can be saved, with exactly only one active at a configurable date/time.

to solve the problem of reloading a new config uppon change, I created 3 policy to propagate a new config:

- listen to signal for config model change and update the config (work in mono process env)
- check new config every minutes with  thread (like your code)
- listen to signal for config change but propagate the event via a amqp message backend. (this is the most optimised solution).

check https://github.com/Yupeek/django-dynamic-logging